# How to do a multidimensional slice in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

For example:

```
array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

slice = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]

output = [[1, 1, 2], [4, 5,6]]
```

I've tried `array[slice]`, but that didn't work. I also couldn't get `tf.gather` or `tf.gather_nd` to work, although these initially seemed like the correct functions to use. Note that these are all tensors in-graph.

How can I select these values in my array according to slice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a dimension to your `slice` tensor which you can do with `tf.pack` and then we can use `tf.gather_nd` no problem.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
old_slice = tf.constant([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2]])

# We need to add a dimension - we need a tensor of rank 2, 3, 2 instead of 2, 3
dims = tf.constant([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]])
new_slice = tf.pack([dims, old_slice], 2)
out = tf.gather_nd(tensor, new_slice)
```

If we run the follow code:

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  run_tensor, run_slice, run_out = sess.run([tensor, new_slice, out])
  print 'Input tensor:'
  print run_tensor
  print 'Correct param for gather_nd:'
  print run_slice
  print 'Output:'
  print run_out
```

This should give the correct output:

```
Input tensor:
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
Correct param for gather_nd:
[[[0 0]
  [0 0]
  [0 1]]

 [[1 0]
  [1 1]
  [1 2]]]
Output:
[[1 1 2]
 [4 5 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

An even easier way to calculate the results, which is also of more general nature, is to directly leverage the `batch_dims` argument of [tf.gather](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather):

```
>>> array = tf.constant([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
>>> slice = tf.constant([[0,0,1], [0,1,2]])
>>> output = tf.constant([[1,1,2], [4,5,6]])
>>> tf.gather(array, slice, batch_dims=1, axis=1)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 1, 2],
       [4, 5, 6]], dtype=int32)>
```